# Can you use a bonus action in the middle of an attack (e.g. after the attack roll, but before the outcome is determined)?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, attack-roll, bonus-action, triggered-actions

Say you're a paladin, and you want to cast [*searing smite*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/searing-smite) (PHB, p. 274).

Can I roll my attack, see the result, and decide if I want to spend my bonus action on *searing smite* before the outcome is determined?

Taking this a step further, can I do it *after* the outcome is known (so I know I will hit)?

---

Relevant quotes from Jeremy Crawford, D&D 5E Development Lead:

- > [(1) You make an attack roll. (2) You hit or miss. (3) You roll damage if you hit. "When you hit" happens at number 2.](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/802204749315485696)
- > [{The quote below} was addressing bonus actions and reactions that have triggers. A bonus action that has no trigger—such as Cunning Action and the misty step spell—can take place whenever you want on your turn (PH, 189).](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/995134313841676288)
- > [No general rule allows you to insert a bonus action between attacks in a single action. You can interrupt a multiple-attack action with a bonus action/reaction only if the trigger of the bonus action/reaction is an attack, rather than the action.](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/995024061267767298)

Crawford's quotes above are about timing related to things like spending a bonus action between attacks, or defining how certain abilities determine when the "hit" is calculated in the damage formula.

Can something as general as a bonus action interfere with the "steps" of the attack roll if it has no required trigger?

We know that something like the [*shield*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shield) spell can directly interfere with these steps (as the spell's trigger requires an attack that "hits" you, but then the AC bonus applied can then negate that hit from occurring).  However, is that specifically due to the *shield* spell's trigger and magical effect, or is it using a general rule?

---

Other related questions:

- [Can you use a bonus action from Cunning Action in the middle of an Attack action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/90779/can-you-use-a-bonus-action-from-cunning-action-in-the-middle-of-an-attack-action)
- [Can you use a bonus action between the separate attacks of a spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169146/can-you-use-a-bonus-action-between-the-separate-attacks-of-a-spell)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you break up your Attack action for a bonus action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72888/can-you-break-up-your-attack-action-for-a-bonus-action)

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Unfortunately not, but it's a good linked question.  The reason is actually because the justification behind that answer was a JC tweet that, ironically, was followed up by the one in my question!   That is, JC corrected himself and the full ruling is: "You can't interrupt an attack action with an attack trigger, unless that trigger requires an attack and not the attack action.  Bonus actions or other effects without triggers are exempt from this", and something like Searing Smite doesn't have a trigger to spend the Bonus Action (unlike Shield Master, the original concern).

Comment: @Daniel Crawford later followed up on that same tweet: "A bonus action that has no trigger—such as Cunning Action and the misty step spell—can take place whenever you want on your turn" however *all* of his tweets are not official rulings.

Comment: For those downvoting, could you provide insight on what could be done to improve the question?  I've tried providing sources, related questions, and reasonable justification, but I'm not sure what else is needed for this to be a perfect question.

Comment: @Medix2 True. That's why I'm asking the community and not answering it myself with a JC tweet.

Comment: I see the difference here, good question. I’m retracting close vote.

Comment: @DanielZastoupil In seeing how you’ve explained the question, I think *you* have enough for a good answer here, don’t hesitate to post your own answer here. It’s a *good* thing when thinking through our own questions leads us to a conclusion.

Comment: @DanielZastoupil: If your reason for asking this question is just that "the answer to the other question asking the same thing is [insufficient/wrong/whatever]" but the questions themselves are the same, the way to handle said dupe would probably be to leave comments on that answer pointing out the issue or to start a bounty on the other question. ...That said, it seems like your question is unique in that it asks about interrupting a single attack itself (not the Attack action) with the act of casting a spell (and specifically casting *searing smite* between attack roll and outcome).

Comment: Putting the related questions together:  "[Can you choose to use abilities like Stunning Strike or Divine Smite after rolling damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/171891)" and "[Can a thrown javelin be catapult-ed back?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/122181)" and "[Are getting hit and taking damage simultaneous events?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/153591)" and "[When using a smite spell cast on a previous turn, can you use your bonus action to apply another smite spell to the same attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/167295)"

Answer (score 4):

### No

To understand it, we should carefully read the Section [Making an Attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MakinganAttack). Once you have declared your attack, calculated the proper modifiers, you resolve the attack

> 3. Resolve the attack. You make the attack roll. On a hit, you roll damage, unless the particular attack has rules that specify otherwise. Some attacks cause special effects in addition to or instead of damage.

From my understanding, all of this occurs without the player being able to take any other action in between. This is a **general rule**. Some features, however, have a specific rule that allows them to be declared between the hit and dealing damage, for example, Divine Smite

> **when you hit a creature with a melee weapon attack**, you can expend one spell slot to deal radiant damage to the target, in addition to the weapon's damage.

This is triggered specifically by the hit, so it is a **specific rule** that allows the player to break the general rule that nothing should be declared after the hit, but before the damage.

The other smites have no such specific rule, and therefore they can not be used that way.

This is backed up by the fact that [hitting and dealing damage are simultaneous events (in-game)](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/153591/43856), therefore, the **character can not perform an action in between them**.

### Probably Intended

The other smites, from my understanding, are supposed to be cast before the attack. If it was intended that they were used like Divine Smite, they would use a similar wording, specifically allowing the player to choose to use them in between hit and damage. The reason Divine Smite is strong is precisely because you can choose to use it only after you hit, never wasting a spell slot for it.

Comment: @disobedienttiger This is my reading of it. All of this is a simultaneous event. If you disagree, then you may want to discuss it [in this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/153591/43856).

Comment: Your post read as though you were deriving " all of this occurs without the player being able to take any other action in between" from the quoted block "3. Resolve the attack...", so I was asking how you derived it.But it is moot, because someone deleted my original comment.

Comment: @disobedienttiger Yes, and all of that is aside this question and this answer, and has already been discussed **in the question I have linked**. The final step is simply stating that if two events are simultaneous you can't act between them because, well, they are simultaneous. What may be confusing you is that they are separate *meta*-events, but it doesn't matter if your feature can't interact with meta events (e.g. Shield does). Either way I'm not interested in discussing this *in this question*. I think my answer is clear enough.