# Do all creatures moved by Fiery Teleportation have to move in the same direction?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, unearthed-arcana, teleportation

The [UA Wildfire druid](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-TwilightFireNames.pdf#page=2)'s wildfire spirit has an ability called Fiery Teleportation with the following description:

> ***Fiery Teleportation (Recharges after a Short or Long Rest).*** The spirit and each willing creature of your choice within 5 feet of it teleport up to 30 feet to unoccupied spaces you can see. Each creature within 10 feet of the space that the spirit left must succeed on a Dexterity saving throw against your spell save DC or take 1d6 + 2 fire damage.

Does this move all the affected creatures as a single group, landing them all within 5 ft of the spirit's new location, or can you move each one independently? For example, if you were surrounded by another group, could you teleport your group outward to be surrounding them, or could you only shift your entire group in the same direction?

Comment: Related: "[Does the Scatter spell actually scatter the targets?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/159568)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### There is no restriction on the direction of teleportation in this feature

Because the rule says simply that creatures are teleported "up to 30 feet to unoccupied spaces you can see," and because it states no further restrictions on the target location, therefore, there aren't any.

As long as you can see unoccupied spaces within 30 feet of their original spaces, then they can be teleported to those various spaces.

Comment: The Tasha's Cauldron of Everything version has the same wording, except for nerfing the distance to 15 feet.  ("*The spirit and each willing creature of your choice within 5 feet of it teleport up to 15 feet to unoccupied spaces you can see*").  So this answer is still correct.